# Suggestion regarding free Natural Language Processing API for Xamarin Android app

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I would like to develop a Natural language Processing App in Xamarin Android,I am looking for free API to use in my APP through google search I found OpenNLP is a free API to do tokenization, Parts of speech tagging etc but I dont know how to use this in my Xamarin Android APP. When I tried to install from Nuget package I am getting an incompitable error Please help me to find free API

Error   NU1202  Package OpenNLP 1.3.5 is not compatible with monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0). Package OpenNLP 1.3.5 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)   OCR Pro C:\Users\Krant\source\repos\OCR Pro\OCR Pro.csproj  1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error,we will find that the Nuget is only available for .net framework >= 4.5

> Error NU1202 Package OpenNLP 1.3.5 is not compatible with
>   monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0). Package OpenNLP 1.3.5
>   supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5) OCR Pro
>   C:\Users\Krant\source\repos\OCR Pro\OCR Pro.csproj 1

So you can't install it for Xamarin Android project , only classic desktop .Net Framework applications.e.g. uwp or wpf.